# Make unittest wait for task to finish

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, unit-testing, sleep, python-unittest

I'm making unittests for timed processes, in my test there are some cases that depend on a timed action, for instance:

```
class MovementTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def goto_test(self):
    self.robot.goto(3, 4, 10)  # go to x=3, y=4 in 10 seconds
    # wait the 10 seconds
    # the objective of the test is that the robot is able to get to (3, 4) in
    # 10 seconds, that's why I need the waiting
    self.assertEqual(self.robot.position, (3, 4))
```

The problem is that when I used `time.sleep(10)`, the program just didn't wait, and therefore the test fails. Is there a way I can make unittest wait the desired time for this test case, also it would be nice if some other tests could run while the waiting is being done.

I tried with threads but the result where that the test checking finishes, the test program waits but the assertions where not checked.

Comment: Just for the record: I would look into ways to change the concept of "time" when doing unit tests. You **absolutely** do not want that your unit tests take more than a few seconds; and having the unit test sitting there 10 seconds to wait for something in your production code is bad practice. So, my first goal would be to manipulate the tested code to not need 10 seconds in a **testing** setup.

Comment: I agree with @GhostCat, please post the code under test to give more context on the problem you're trying to solve.